# How would you put this "IIR Approximation of FIR Filters Via Discrete-Time Vector Fitting" into Matlab?

Tags: matlab, filters, finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response

https://www.eee.hku.hk/~culei/publication/ISCAS-0590.pdf

This paper talks about a way to approximate FIR filters using IIR via a method known as Discrete-Time Vector Fitting. I am confused on how I would implement this into Matlab.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Help you in what exactly? ... You can start implementing its Matlab code, then if you got any issue, you'd write it here.

Comment: I am not sure how to implement it, it is not explained how to implement it

Comment: Actually, In my opinion, I suggest you  try avoid spending much time trying to understand a conference paper or low-ranked published paper since their results are not always guaranteed. Many of them are just writing mathematical formulas and then add results which are not 100% correct.

Comment: @user It's absolutely as Zeyad_Zeyad says: you are not actually asking a question, you're just shouting out "I don't know what to do"; we can't really answer that with a precise answer! So, start somewhere. If you're not familiar with matlab, start with a matlab tutorial. Once you're stuck somewhere, and it's a signal processing problem that you can put into words, ask here :)